# Where can I pick up the World Trigger manga after watching the anime?

Tags: world-trigger

I am guessing that the anime is ended by the way it looks on Crunchyroll's Episode 73 - "To The Future" of World Trigger.

If anyone has seen the anime and read the manga, if the anime is indeed cancelled, where would i pick up the story in the Manga?

Comment: the last episode corresponds with ch 124

Comment: The author had a severe illness that caused the manga to go on Hiatus 3 months ago. Japan is starting a rebroadcast of the series, so it may be coming back soon.

Comment: correction, it's been over a year. Last official word was 3 months ago that it is still on hiatus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to BakaUpdates the anime starts at chapter 1 and ends at chapter 122 of the manga.

https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=92323